# sortablejs methods not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sortablejs

Implementing sortablejs with Rails 6.  Everything going swimmingly until I tried to use the toArray method and now for the life of me I can't get things to work.

I am instantiating sortable in a stimulus controller as follows:

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus";
import Sortable from "sortablejs"

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    this.sortable = Sortable.create(this.element, {
        animation: 150,
        filter: 'input, button,',
        onEnd: this.end.bind(this)
    })

console.log($("#sort-me"));
}  
end(event) {
    console.log(event)
    var sortable = this.sortable;
    let combo_id = event.item.dataset.id
    let entry_id = combo_id.substr(0, combo_id.indexOf("_"));
    let id = combo_id.substr(combo_id.indexOf("_") + 1, combo_id.length);

    let current_order = $('#image_order_array_' + entry_id).val();
    let current_position = $('#image_position_' + id).val();

    let data = new FormData()
    data.append("current_order", current_order)
    data.append("current_position", current_position)
    data.append("new_position", event.newIndex)
    data.append("old_position", event.oldIndex)

    var idsInOrder = $("#sort-me").sortable("toArray");

    Rails.ajax({
      url: this.data.get("url").replace(":id", id),
      type:'PATCH',
      data: data      
  
    })

    }   
 }
```

When the end event fires I get:

```
 drag_controller.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function
```

I've tried many diff permutations of this and can't get working.  Basically once an item is sorted I need to get the toArray values so I know the current order of the items.

Comment: looks like sortable is null for some reason right?

Comment: In this example, seems so.  I tried a bunch of ways...all produce errors.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:     this.sortable.toArray